# Неправильно работает сравнение, можете объяснить?

Tags: javascript

Почему false, а не true? Ведь приведение типов должно было сработать при ==

```js
console.log(!!'строка со значением')
console.log('строка со значением' == true)
```

Comment: Потому что тут строка не преобразуется в булево, а ноборот: булева приводится к строке?))

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
Тут написано, что идёт преобразование к ToNumber(A) === ToNumber(B)

Comment: Очень странно, сколько изучал, в итоге так и не понял. Пустая строка является ложные значением. Строка со значением считается истинным. == означает что сравнение происходит с приведением типов. Соответственно строка приведенное в тип = true , true == true должно быть тоже true(

Comment: И почему булево к строке, а не наоборот? Как это понять?

Comment: @xmikex мммм. значит получается итоговое сравнение получается NaN == 1. Думаю можно написать это для автора)

Comment: Иван, так сделай явное приведение строки к типу bool и после этого делай сравнение. Неявно оба значения приводятся к числовому представлению, а не к булеву.

Answer (score -2):

Быть может потому что

```js
console.log('строка со значением' === undefined)
```

Comment: Tatarincev не совсем понял(

Comment: если вам надо проверять объявлена ли переменная, необходимо использовать оператор строгого соответствия (без приведения типов)